# Easy way to add Functional or Kernel tests to a View?

Tags: 9, testing

I have an administrative View that has a couple access checks based on current user. I would like to add an automated test to the view.

Since I only need to check the result count (no specific field) based on whats set in a users profile, how can I test this view?

Fields I will normally scaffold in setUp() using FieldConfig class, is there a similar one for Views?

These run in CI (I don't know how DTT works in this regard) and the View is apt to change, copying a YAML file into a module can often be forgot (and carry many dependencies with it).

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using Drupal Test Traits.

The only thing left for me to do is obtain a copy of the database to run the tests in CI, which I can use Drush to grab.